# How do I round a double to one decimal place?

Tags: java, double

I am trying to get a random double returned to me in the format #.# however I am getting a value of something to this effect: 0.9395772067578356

How do you force only a one decimal  return on a random double as I cannot put paraments in the .nextDouble.

```
        myRandomNumGenerator = new Random();
        loadedValue = myRandomNumGenerator.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat oneDigit = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");//format to 1 decimal place

System.out.println(oneDigit.format(anyVariable)); //generic usage

loadedValue = Double.valueOf(oneDigit.format(loadedValue));//specific usage posted in comments
```

Comment: had to add `loadedValue = Double.valueOf(oneDigit.format(loadedValue));` for comparison purposes, but it did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can force a one place return.  You can just make it print the one place, however.

```
System.out.printf("%.1f", loadedValue);
```

That will print the value to one place.